# http error 500 every day only in a specific time of the day

Tags: php, mysql, apache, http

I have the 500 http errors every day in the time between 1:00 - 2:00 and only at this time.

My web it's in a shared server of 1and1 and I think it should be some problem with a maintenance process scheduled at this time because the error always appears at the same time (more or less) and the rest of the day all it's ok.

I've contacted with 1and1 and they are investigating it but I don't trust on them.

I've seen in the log that during this problematic period the http calls to some image for example it works (return code 200). But the calls to a php file with a mySql query fails with 500.

Could be some problem with too muchs access to databases? is the 500 error possible in this cases?

In this scripts I access to a file located in a protected folder (rwx------) to take the user and password. I don't know if it matters.

What can I do to try to know more about the problem?

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? Do they show any more detail as to the exact error that is occurring?

Comment: Please post the _specific_ errors from your error log.  A failing MySQL query is something to investigate, but not for us to speculate on.

Comment: In the server log I have hundreds on lines like this: 190.111.26.6 - - [04/Apr/2014:01:03:22 +0200] "POST /api/getNotes.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - www.noteboardapp.com "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: I don't have more information in the logs.

Comment: we have a client also having similar problems with 1&1 hosted space... would advice you to move the hoster

Answer (score 0):

**Some causes of 500 Internal Server Errors**

> 1.File permissons set incorrectly.
>
> 2.Coding errors in the .htaccess file.

Analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

Comment: But I only have errors in a specific period of time. If I have some file permission bad or a htaccess file wrong why only fails at some time?

Comment: Refer PHP Coding Timing Out

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1903/Why+am+I+getting+a+500+Internal+Server+Error+message%3F